# resize svg image in java

Tags: java, svg, resize

I'm facing a small but annoying issue. I have an svg image, say "test.svg". I display it with a special Swing component (SVGPanel from SVGSalamander if you're interested, but it doesn't matter). So, **I have my "test.svg" perfectly displayed**, I can also resize it as I wish. Now, my issue is that when I resize my swing component, **I would like to modify the size of "test.svg"**.

My first intent was to modify the width and height attributes of the `<svg>` element, but of course it doesn't work as expected, because the coordinates of the objects become wrong.

For instance, if I have an horizontal line in the middle of a svg panel :

```
    //Should be sth like that
    <svg ... height='20' width='20'><line x1="0" x2="20" y1="10" y2="10" /></svg>
```

If I try to resize it by changing only the size, I will get :

```
    //using my "naive" resize method
    <svg ... height='10' width='10'><line x1="0" x2="20" y1="10" y2="10" /></svg>
```

and the line is not anymore in the middle of the panel. Instead, it is now on the bottom.

All of this is probably very obvious. Sorry if it's the case.

So, in brief, **how can I get the expected result** :

```
    <svg ... height='10' width='10'><line x1="0" x2="10" y1="5" y2="5" /></svg>
```

Thanks a lot for your help !

Comment: You'll need to take all the objects and recalculate width/height/x/y for each of them. If there isn't a library to work with this, you'll have to download an XML parser and do it from scratch

Comment: Are you serious ? But I have no idea how many kind of objects and attributes there could be ! Maybe anyone knows at least a small library that could do the work ?

Comment: Yes I'm serious. And yes, wait for other feedbacks, as I don't know if there is any SVG library for this purpose. If there is one, things will be much easier!

Comment: Wait, I randomly hit sth in google about the viewbox attribute. I think it may be the key

Comment: Im not really sure why you would want to resize an SVG considering its "Scalable Vector Graphics" and dimensions are meant to be scaled upon painting the object, therefore I couldnt imagine anyone writing one. Is there another reason your looking to resize the dimensions of a SVG?

Comment: I want to define the "default" displaying size. When I open the file, for instance, I want it to appear with a specific size that I chose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

put a viewBox attribute on the `<svg>` element e.g. `viewBox="0 0 20 20"`. Now you can change the width/height without the contents being affected.

Comment: Yes, exactly. That's what I was trying to achieve after I discovered this attribute.